# passing parameters to mouseenter/mouseout JS callbacks

Tags: javascript, html, dom, frontend

I'm presented this challenge where the circle's color is to change depending on the type of cursor movement.

I must use the function toggleColor() in order to fill the circle with orange when the cursor moves onto it. Then, I got to reuse the same function to fill it in black once the cursor leaves it.

This must be done calling the toggleColor() with different values for the parameter isEntering. (In order to do this, I'm invoking the .toggleColor() function inside the callbacks of the .addEventListener()'s.

```
const element = document.querySelector('#element');

const toggleColor = (isEntering) => {
element.style.background = isEntering ? 'orange' : 'black';
};

element.addEventListener('mouseenter', ()=>toggleColor(true))
element.addEventListener('mouseout', ()=>toggleColor(false))
```

That's my solution to the challenge, and even though it does the work, the tests are not passing. Where am I failing at?

Here is the link to the challenge: https://www.jschallenger.com/javascript-dom-exercises/events-and-user-interactions/cursor-enter-leave-event

Comment: I just copy pasted your code and passed all the test cases.

Comment: site is broken .

Comment: element.addEventListener('mouseover', ()=>toggleColor(true)). Replace  mouserenter with mouseover. And I also copy pasted your code and passed test.

Answer (score 0):

The correct is:
element.addEventListener('mouseover', () => toggleColor(true));
element.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => toggleColor(false));

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I used the following and it worked for me. Hope this helps.

```js
element.onmouseenter = () => toggleColor(true);    
element.onmouseleave = () => toggleColor(false);
```